# Asking for a user's input in a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

For my code, I'm required to create a function that asks the user to input a row between 1 and 3,  and a column between 1 and 3 (pretty much like tic tac toe) and then use those numbers in order to place an 'X' on the place that the user asked for. I'm stuck on the human input part, because I keep on getting a name error, and that my variable is not defined. I've tried defining my variable outside of the function, but then I just get 0.

Here is the code (row_size has already been defined and pretend that in this code that row_size is three).

```
def human():
   choice_row = int(input('Input the row where you want to put X between 1 and ' + str(row_size) + ': ')) 
    while True:
        try:
            if choice_row > 1 and choice_row < row_size:
                return choice_row
            else:
                print('ERROR. The row should be an integer between 1 and ' + str(row_size))
        except:
            print('ERROR. The row should be an integer between 1 and ' + str(row_size))
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is wrong placement of `while` loop and try..except

```
def human():
   while True:
     try:
       choice_row = int(input('Input the row where you want to put X between 1 and ' + str(row_size) + ': ')) 
     except ValueError:
       print("Enter a number pls")
     
     if choice_row > 1 and choice_row < row_size:
       return choice_row
     else:
       print('ERROR. The row should be an integer between 1 and ' + str(row_size))
```